# Perform mirror symmetry transformation of 3D model (in OBJ)

Tags: graphics3d

I have a full three-dimensional model in OBJ format:

[image: Bitmap of OBJ model]

and I would like to perform a mirror symmetry operation... that is, reverse each point front-to-back.  Because this model is spatially asymmetric, this mirror reflection is *not* equivalent to a rotation.  (This is a common misunderstanding.)

Here is a two-dimensional image of what I seek.  (Note, it is not a rotation of the figure.)  But I seek a full 3D model in this configuration.

[image]

In particular, I want to produce a graphic where we see the figure and his reflection in a plane mirror.  Thus the figure will face to the right and his reflected image will face to the left but we (the viewers) will see his hand in his pocket facing us.

How do I perform that mirror operation on the figure to produce his (virtual) mirror-symmetric image?

---

The model was downloaded [here](https://free3d.com/3d-model/dennis-posed-004-812878.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion). For example:

```
obj = Import @ FileNameJoin[{
    $HomeDirectory,
    "Downloads",
    "86-rp_dennis_posed_004_bld_free3d",
    "rp_dennis_posed_004_100k.OBJ"
}];
```

Using [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion):

```
Show[
    obj,
    TransformedRegion[
        obj,
        TranslationTransform[{100, 0, 0}] @* ScalingTransform[{-1, 1, 1}]
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so very much.  ($\checkmark$).  (Although I didn't ask it... I notice that the lighting is "incorrect".  A full mirror-symmetric operation would flip the lighting direction as well.)

Comment: We can also use `ReflectionTransform`.

Comment: I was looking exactly for this! Now I'm going to have *ALL 3D MODELS* for my talk on chirality.